# Which things are necessary when sharing memory between different processors?

Tags: c++, c, arm, signal-processing, shared-memory

So I have an ARM processor and a DSP processor. Some data would be shared between those two processor using a shared memory. The data could consist of data structures such as structs and classes of C++. Which things are important to make the application work with this sort of shared memory. One thing that comes to the mind is endianness, that is both processors should either be little endian or big endian. Anything else, which is also necessary to ensure proper shared memory accesses?

Comment: Cortex-A Series Programmer’s Guide http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0013d/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from Endianness, following might be important,

1. Implementation of standard api's might differ and can have adverse effects on shared data e.g. memcpy() on ARM is implemented in a unique way internally and i at least remember having a hard time with a bug porting an RTOS to ARM. I don't recall the exact details but those surely can be found with a little search.
2. Strictly use types and structures aligned by the tool chains. Because alignment and padding for each architecture might be totally different. So you would be in for a surprise if you try indexing values inside a struct using pointer / array indexing.

Comment: It's also likely that the 2 processors have separate L1 and L2 caches that would need to be manually kept in sync.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the issues in Fayyazki's answer there are several additional hurdles to the arrangement you describe.

1. Synchronisation: In all likelihood, you will need a pair of doorbell interrupts so that the CPU and DSP can interrupt each other to notify each other of communication.   The alternative is polling - which is unlikely to result in high throughput.
2. Atomicity: Writing multi-word structures (e.g. C++ classes) to shared memory is problematic as you have none of the synchronisation mechanisms you might use in other circumstances such as bus-locking or disabling interrupts. You could use spin-locks to control read and write access if you insist on writing multiword structures to the shared memory. Controlling the memory packing of your structures may in fact result in *more* multi-word accesses.
3. Concurrent memory access - if you are using true multi-port SRAM, concurrent writes on the same address will be non-predictable.  You therefore don't do this.
4. Memory/instruction order barriers: You will need to use memory barriers to ensure that writes are observed on the memory bus in the order you expect (many Cortex A-series ARM CPUs have out-of-order execution and store behaviour).  This is in addition to either making the address range of the memory uncachable or flushing the cache.

By far the easiest approach to implementing communications between the two processors is to use a [ring buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) in which the writing head and tail pointers are the natural word-size of the memory  and are maintained by the writing processor and reading processor respectively.  You will need barrier (both memory and instruction order) after writing data to the buffer and updating the head pointer to ensure writes into the buffer are observed by memory before updating the head pointer.  Reads work in reverse.

Comment: Might want to use two ring buffers, one for each direction of communication.

Comment: Absolutely. Not trivially concurrency safe otherwise.

Comment: Good coverage +1, specially mentioning ring buffers. I shouldn't have forgotten that. I would add that these are very standard and generic across many architectures. Even right now, i am working on a well known multicore network processor family which is MIPS based and its standard mechanism when communication with a host over PCI is through rings - one for each side.

Comment: Ring buffer ususally use words for the head and tail which need to be shared between these 2 processors. How do you sync these words between processors ?

Answer (score 2):

ARM's weakly-ordered memory model means you'll likely have to be very careful with synchronisation and coherency if you're using cacheable memory - if this is the case I'd recommend a thorough read of the brain-melting memory model chapters of the [ARM ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0406c/index.html) (and possibly the barriers appendix).

Also, if the two processors have different views of the same memory (*à la* Raspberry Pi), then having pointers in the shared data could be fun*...

<sub>* for some given value of "fun"</sub>

Comment: I recall being able to use ARM's memory management to set regions to read only, read / write, ... , but I don't recall if there's a way to set a region to non-cacheable. I don't know if this is possible with the DSP. The alternative would be some method to flush all caches just before communicating between processors.

Comment: @rcgldr The memory type, shareability and cacheability attribute bits live in the same place as the access control bits (translation table descriptor/control register for VMSA/PMSA respectively).